# Learning an Infinite Vector

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Choose $(a_1, a_2 , a_3 \dots)$ (this is an infinite sequence) in such a way

that

$$ \frac{2|a_3|^p + |a_1 + a_2 + a_4|^p + \sum_{j=2}^{\infty}|a_j + a_{j+2}|^p }{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_j|^p} $$

can come close to $3$ with arbitrary precision $\epsilon$ and so that

$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_j|^p < \infty$ (so that the sequence converges).

What work and algorithms in machine learning might help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you're looking for, but take $a_5 = a_6 = \dots = 0$ so that your problem reduces to finding $a_1, \dots, a_4$ such that
$$
f(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4) := \frac{2|a_3|^p + |a_1 + a_2 + a_4|^p + |a_2 + a_4|^p + |a_4|^p }{\sum_{i=1}^{4}|a_j|^p} = 3.
$$

We can easily solve this using least squares. Here's an example in R:

```
f <- function(avec, p) {
  (2 * abs(avec[3])^p + abs(sum(avec[-3]))^p + abs(avec[2] + avec[4])^p + abs(avec[4])^p) / sum(abs(avec)^p)
}

obj_func <- function(avec, p) {
  (f(avec, p) - 3)^2
}

opt <- optim(par=c(.1, .1, .1, .1), fn=obj_func, p=2.5)

print(opt$par)  # 0.1311438 0.1052790 0.1506071 0.0189061
print(f(opt$par, 2.5))  #  3.000105
```

And you can get a more accurate answer by changing the convergence tolerance and increasing the precision.